# Problems with initiating different models in openGl with c++

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, visual-studio-2015, vao

I'm learning openGL and I'm trying to do something very simple. I have a graphics object called Model which contains a vector of GLfloats for vertices and has a draw function. In addition to this, I have an addVertex function which takes in 3 floats and a draw function which binds the object's VAO and then unbinds it after drawing. I have no problem rendering one of these objects and adding points to it, however I can't draw more than one of these at the same time without the program crashing and visual studio's telling me "Frame not in module" which isn't helpful. Also, only the last Model object I create can be rendered, any object that comes before it will crash the program.

Here's the Model object's code:

```
#include "Model.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



Model::Model() {

    drawMode = 0;


    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO); 
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

Model::~Model() {
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
}

void Model::addVertex(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z) {
    vertices.push_back(x);
    vertices.push_back(y);
    vertices.push_back(z);
    update();
}

void Model::addIndex(int i, int j, int k) {
    indices.push_back(i);
    indices.push_back(j);
    indices.push_back(k);


}
void Model::setShader(GLuint& shader) {
    shaderProgram = &shader;
}



void Model::clearModel() {
    vertices.clear();
    indices.clear();
}

int Model::sizeOfVertices() {
    return sizeof(GLfloat)*vertices.size();
}
int Model::sizeOfIndices() {
    return sizeof(GLuint)*(indices.size());
}

void Model::draw() {
    glUseProgram(*shaderProgram);
    GLuint transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(*shaderProgram, "model");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));


    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    switch (drawMode) {
    case 0: glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertices.size() / 3);
        break;
    case 1: glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, vertices.size() / 3);
        break;
    case 2: glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size() / 3);
        break;
    case 3: glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.size() / 3);
        break;
    default: break;
    }

    glBindVertexArray(0); 

}

void Model::setDrawMode(int type) {
    drawMode = type;
}


void Model::move(glm::vec3 translation) {
    model = glm::translate(model, translation);
}
void Model::rotate(float degrees,glm::vec3 axis) {
    model = glm::rotate(model, degrees,axis);
}

void Model::update() {
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeOfVertices(), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

}
```

There is an EBO included in the Model class but I'm not using it yet as I want to isolate the problem.

Model.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>;
#include <glew.h>;

#include "glm.hpp"
#include "gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "gtc/type_ptr.hpp"
#include "gtc/constants.hpp"

class Model {
public:
    int drawMode;
    GLuint VAO;
    GLuint VBO;
    GLuint EBO;
    GLuint *shaderProgram;
    std::vector<GLfloat> vertices;
    std::vector<GLuint> indices;

    glm::mat4 model;

    Model();
    ~Model();

    void addVertex(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat);
    void addIndex(int, int, int);

    void setShader(GLuint&);

    void clearModel();

    int sizeOfVertices();
    int sizeOfIndices();

    void draw();
    void setDrawMode(int);

    void move(glm::vec3);
    void rotate(float, glm::vec3);

    void update();
};
```

Main class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


#include <vector>

#include "Callbacks.h"
#include "Shader.h"
#include "GlState.h"
#include "Model.h"

#include <glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include "glm.hpp"
#include "gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "gtc/type_ptr.hpp"
#include "gtc/constants.hpp"



Model *model;
Model *model2;
Model *model3;

void mainLoop(GLFWwindow* window) {
    glfwPollEvents();
//RENDER UNDER HERE
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPointSize(5);


        Callbacks::update(model3);
        model3->draw();
        model2->draw();
        model->draw();



    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

}


int main() {
    GLFWwindow* window = GlState::Initialize(800,600);
    GLuint shaderProgram = Shader::makeProgram("vertex.vs", "fragment1.fs");
    GLuint shaderProgram2 = Shader::makeProgram("vertex.vs", "fragment2.fs");
    model = new Model();
    model2 = new Model();
    model3 = new Model();


    model->setShader(shaderProgram);
    model2->setShader(shaderProgram);
    model3->setShader(shaderProgram2);


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        mainLoop(window);

    }

    delete(model);
    delete(model2);
    delete(model3);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I'll also include the important part of Callbacks, which is called by update(Model* m)

```
void Callbacks::checkMouse(Model* m) {
    if (leftMousePressed) {
        if (tics == 0) {
            m->addVertex(2*(mouseXCurrent-0.5), 2*(0.5-mouseYCurrent), 0.0f);

        }
    tics++;
    }
}
```

I haven't set the camera yet so its in default orthographic view.

Since I can only add points to the last Model object initiated without crashing (model3 in this case), I assume it must be something to do with the way these models are being initiated but I can't figure out what! It's driving me nuts.

So an example of it crashing:

after the code segment in main:

```
    model->setShader(shaderProgram);
    model2->setShader(shaderProgram);
    model3->setShader(shaderProgram2);
```

if you input 
    model->addVertex(0.1f,0.2f,0.0f);
or
    model2->addVertex(0.1f,0.2f,0.0f);

the program will crash, however

```
model3->addVertex(0.1f,0.2f,0.0f);
```

works with no problems

Comment: So far I could not find some mistakes. But one thing I noticed is, that you use the vertices.size() function to calculate to count of vertices to draw for the glDrawArrays call. But this can be getting dangerous if you change some data of vertices without updating the buffer data because you may try to draw vertices which does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

The code will crash because you are accessing data outside of the buffers. In the constructor, you create buffers with size `NULL`:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

Note that the pointer type `NULL` is totally invalide for the `size` argument of that call, but that is not the issue here.

When you call the `addVertex` method, you append the data to your `std::vector`, but *not to the VBO*. Yo never call the `update` method which actually transfers the data into your buffer, so your attribute pointers still point to the 0-sized buffer, and when drawing more than 0 vertices from that, you're just in undefined-behavior land.

Comment: My mistake with the update(), it is called after add vertex however it was originally in the Callback::checkMouse(), and when I removed it from checkMouse here I did not add it in addVertex() here. It was in my code though, so that was not the error. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I found what the problem is. Within the update method, I would bind the VAO and the problem was that I assumed this also bound the VBO for editing which apparently never happened. So when I called

`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeOfVertices(), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);`

I thought I was modifying the VBO within the VAO, but I was actually modifying the last VBO bound. The last time the VBO was bound was in the constructor, so this is why I was only able to modify the last Model object created, and the other ones would crash because I would bind their VAO and attempt to modify another Model's VBO.

At least I assume this was the problem as there is no error now because I'm calling

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
```

before I modify it.